# how to check if the array is empty and length

Tags: sql

I have table like this, the e-id is a array,it can be empty, one or more elements,  how can I filter the id which has zero, one or more elements of e-id? thank you so much!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could try to using the `ARRAY_CONCAT` function and check if the string is equal to `""`